# How to use store and dispatcher only from Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

All:

I am pretty new to Redux, when I follow the tutorial and reach section 2.5, those concepts like `connect()` `middleware` seem a little bit confused to me(for example, where should `setState()` be in the code ), so I wonder if I only want to use the reducer / store / dispatch parts, how can I update the state of the app?

Thanks

Comment: `connect` is part of of `react-redux`, not `redux`. Start here: https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you don't use `setState()` on a redux application, to update the state, you do it by dispatching an action.

Comment: Thanks, but like I said,  I wonder if I do not use connect(), how can I make redux app aware there is a data change?